# How to convert the single comma array value in multiple key value

Tags: php, arrays

I want to convert the below value

```
Array
(
   [0]=>4,9
)
```

to this value

```
Array
(
   [0]=>4
   [1]=>9
)
```

Comment: Zain Farooq , you know the answer ?

Comment: Apply for each loop on an array then do explode by a comma. You will get your result.

Comment: PD of [Generate Array from a comma-separated list - PHP](//stackoverflow.com/q/10835101) / [PHP: Turn comma-separated values into an array of integers](//stackoverflow.com/q/21359222) / etc.

Comment: Can you explain how you've crafted the initial array? To me, both the first and the second array are the same

Comment: @NicoHaase the outputs are most likely a print_r, so they are not the same. https://3v4l.org/AVFLI

Answer (score 2):

You can use the following solution:

```
<?php
//the current array and an empty new array to get the result.
$cur_array = [0 => "4,9", 1 => "5,9"];
$new_array = [];

//run through all array values to convert these.
for ($i = 0; $i < count($cur_array); $i++) {

    //get an array of the comma separated list.
    $part = explode(',', $cur_array[$i]);

    //add the array of comma separated list to the new array (result).
    $new_array = array_merge($new_array, $part);
}

//convert all string values to integer values.
for ($j = 0; $j < count($new_array); $j++) {
    $new_array[$j] = intval($new_array[$j]);
}

//output of the new array (debug).
var_dump($new_array);
```

> **demo:** https://ideone.com/1WFv4V

... or the following more compact solution using `array_values`:

```
<?php
$oldarr = [0 => "4,9", 1 => "5,9"];
$newarr = [];

foreach (array_values($oldarr) as $arrpart) {
    $newarr = array_merge($newarr, explode(',', $arrpart));
}

var_dump($newarr);
```

In case your values are decimal numbers you can use the following:

```
<?php
$oldarr = [0 => 4.9, 1 => 5.9, 2 => 6];
$newarr = [];

foreach (array_values($oldarr) as $arrpart) {
    $newarr = array_merge($newarr, explode('.', $arrpart));
}

var_dump($newarr);
```

Comment: @Sheenu why is this answer not useful? describe more detailed what you need exactly.

Comment: @Sheenu You should probably expand on your question then. "Check my question" is slighlty bemusing, given that it contains such little effort and context.

Answer (score 0):

```
$array = array( 0 => '4,9');
foreach($array as $data){
  $commaSeparatedArr =  explode(',',$data); 
}
print_r($commaSeparatedArr);
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Pease keep in mind that the value in answers is often the explanation. Code dumps are less helpful to future visitors.

Answer (score 0):

Use implode and explode.
You first implode all values in the array with commas between them, then you explode on comma.

```
$result = explode(",", implode(",", $array));
```

See example: https://3v4l.org/JGOAB

Answer (score -1):

```
$oldarr = [0 => 4,9];

$string = implode(',',$oldarr);

$new_array = explode(',',$string);

print_r($new_array);
```

Comment: This does exactly as you ask, but you should be sure to loop, as shown by @Sebastian Brosch

Comment: Array
(
   [0]=>4,9
)

Comment: and what value you take in variable

Comment: @Sheemu - **be more clear on your question!** `$arr = [0 => 4,9];` is `$arr = [0 => 4, 1 => 9];` (the value you want) - https://ideone.com/OuUGwU.

Comment: That does not work properly: inspect what `$oldarr` contains in the beginning. It does **not** contain the same value that the OP printed

Answer (score -1):

Replace the value of the array.

```
$array = ["4,9,7,14", "7,9,68"];
$new_array = [];
foreach($array as $a) {
   array_map(function($a_r) {
      $new_array[] = (int) $a_r
   }, exlpode(",", $a));
}

var_dump($new_array);

/* Output
Array (
  [0] => int 4,
  [1] => int 9,
  [2] => int 7,
  [3] => int 14,
  [4] => int 7,
  [5] => int 9,
  [6] => int 68
)
*/
```

Comment: What makes you think that the initial array contains a string?

Comment: i think that that's correct, look the new answer. I should be near to your needs.